# How to Install a JQuery Plugin to Rails 5.0 without a Gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coverflow

I'm trying to install this JQuery Plugin: http://coverflowjs.github.io/coverflow/tutorial/get-started/

I'm relatively new to rails, and not sure how to implement a JQuery plugin without a Gem. (And not comfortable trying to create a gem at this point)

Can someone please assist in laying out a step-by-step breakdown of how they would go about installing this plugin?

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use rails-assets.org, which wraps bower components into ruby gems on the fly. Find the equivalent library in bower and then use the gem it creates.

Coverflow is available at https://rails-assets.org/#/components/coverflow

Comment: Note: You should now start using webpacker gem and install these using npm/yard.

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps:

1. Download latest jquery file using link https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js
2. Add file under /assets/javascript folder

OR

Add below code under app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just try this..

You can download the plugin and save it in `vendor/assets/javascripts`. Then you include it on `application.js`

```
//In (for example) application.js

//= require jquery
```

or in some added file like

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do these steps as below:

1. download `coverflowjs` library and put it inside `app/assets/javascripts/` or you can put it inside `vendor/assets/javascripts/`
2. in your file `application.js`, you only put this line.

   `//= require coverflowjs`

Comment: I tried this and got this error `couldn't find file 'coverflowjs' with type 'application/javascript'` I downloaded the file and put the entire unzipped coverflow folder into `vendor/assets/javascripts/`  Is that correct or am I suppose to take out specific files and insert it into that folder?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: no, you just put file with extension `js` inside `javascripts` folder. if you have some files such as `.css` or `.png`,....With extension `.css`, you must put it inside `assets/stylesheets/`